# Keras.NET How to Use KerasIterator

Tags: c#, keras, iterator

I want to do the same as F. Chollet's [notebook](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.3-using-a-pretrained-convnet.ipynb) but in C#.

However, I can't find a way to iterate over my KerasIterator object:

```py
def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 4, 4, 512))
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count))

    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=20,
        class_mode='binary'
    )

    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * 20 : (i + 1) * 20] = features_batch
        labels[i * 20 : (i + 1) * 20] = labels_batch

        i += 1
        if i * 20 >= sample_count:
            break

    return features, labels
```

My current C# function is below.

Details:

- foreach loop gives me a 'Compiler Error CS1579' on KerasIterator
- for loop is not possible because a KerasIterator doesn't have a Length (or Size, etc.)

```cs
private List<NDarray> ExtractFeatures(ImageDataGenerator datagen, String directory, int sample_count)
{
    // create the return NDarrays
    NDarray features = np.zeros(shape: (sample_count, 4, 4, 512));
    NDarray labels = np.zeros(shape: (sample_count, 4, 4, 512));

    KerasIterator generator = datagen.FlowFromDirectory(
        directory,
        target_size: (150, 150).ToTuple(),
        batch_size: 20,
        class_mode: "binary"
    );

    int i = 0;
    /* how do I iterate on 'generator' here, in a similar way than in Python? */

    // return the List element
    return new List<NDarray> { features, labels };
}
```

Comment: If you have a compiler error, please add its complete message and mark the line it refers to. Thx

Comment: Is it this one: [CS1579](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1579)? _"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'type1' because 'type2' does not contain a public definition for 'identifier'"_

Comment: yes it is, to be precise: "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'KerasIterator' because 'KerasIterator' does not contain a public definition or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: I would infer, that `KerasIterator` is not compatible with `foreach`, then. @MindSwipe also seems to have found a correspnding issue (see his answer).

Comment: ok, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of April 19. 2020 it is not possible with the .NET Wrapper as documented in [this](https://github.com/SciSharp/Keras.NET/issues/56) issue on the GitHub page for Keras.NET

Comment: Well ok... So can I find a way around this issue? Is there really no way for me to do as F. Chollet but in C#?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any easy way around this. So it seems like there is really no way to do it the way they did but in C#.